# Complex data calculation for consecutive zeros at row level in R (lag v/s lead)

Tags: r

I have a complex calculation that needs to be done. It is basically at a row level, and i am not sure how to tackle the same.

If you can help me with the approach or any functions, that would be really great.

I will break my problem into two sub-problems for simplicity.

Below is how my data looks like

```
Group,Date,Month,Sales,lag7,lag6,lag5,lag4,lag3,lag2,lag1,lag0(reference),lead1,lead2,lead3,lead4,lead5,lead6,lead7
Group1,42005,1,2503,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1
Group1,42036,2,3734,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
Group1,42064,3,6631,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0
Group1,42095,4,8606,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
Group1,42125,5,1889,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0
Group1,42156,6,4819,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0
Group1,42186,7,5120,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0
```

[image]

I have data for each Group at Monthly Level.

I would like to capture the below two things.

**1. The count of consecutive zeros for each row to-and-fro from lag0(reference)**

The highlighted yellow are the cases, that are consecutive with lag0(reference) to a certain point, that it reaches first 1. I want to capture the count of zero's at row level, along with the corresponding Sales value.

Below is the output i am looking for the part1.

Output:

```
Month,Sales,Count
1,2503,9
2,3734,3
3,6631,5
4,8606,0
5,1889,6
6,4819,1
7,5120,1
```

**2. Identify the consecutive rows(row:1,2 and 3 & similarly row:5,6) where overlap of any lag or lead happens for any 0 within the lag0(reference range), and capture their Sales and Month value.**

For example, for row 1,2 and 3, the overlap happens at atleast lag:3,2,1 & 
lead: 1,2, this needs to be captured and tagged as case1 (or 1). Similarly, for row 5 and 6 atleast lag1 is overlapping, hence this needs to be captured, and tagged as Case2(or 2), along with Sales and Month value.

Now, row 7 is not overlapping with the previous or later consecutive row,hence it will not be captured.

Below is the result i am looking for part2.

```
Month,Sales,Case
1,2503,1
2,3734,1
3,6631,1
5,1889,2
6,4819,2
```

I want to run this for multiple groups, hence i will either incorporate dplyr or loop to get the result. Currently, i am simply looking for the approach.

Not sure how to solve this problem. First time i am looking to capture things at row level in R. I am not looking for any solution. Simply looking for a first step to counter this problem. Would appreciate any leads.

Comment: What exactly is your problem, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand how the "overlap" in the second part is defined. What does it mean when you say "the overlap happens at atleast lag:3,2,1 & lead: 1,2"? Just that there are zeroes present? But there aren't the same number of adjacent zeroes in those rows, so why are they one case?

Comment: Yes. The overlap is only for any zero's at any row level that gets overlapped within the lag(reference) range as mentioned in part1, with any consecutive rows. For row 1,2, and 3, The overlap of zero is happending at lag:3,2,1 and lead:1,2... even if there aren't adjacent zerows in those rows, its not an issue. Any one zero should atleast overlap with the next row, even though the next row may overlap with further row at any other zero (within that lag(reference) range(highlighed in yellow). My apologies, if i am not able to explain properly.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `rle` for the 1st part of the calculation can be as:

```
df$count <- apply(df[,-c(1:4)],1,function(x){
  first <- rle(x[1:7])
  second <- rle(x[9:15])
  count <- 0
  if(first$values[length(first$values)] == 0){
    count = first$lengths[length(first$values)]
  }
  if(second$values[1] == 0){
    count = count+second$lengths[1]
  }
  count

})

df[,c("Month", "Sales", "count")]
  # Month Sales count
# 1     1  2503     9
# 2     2  3734     3
# 3     3  6631     5
# 4     4  8606     0
# 5     5  1889     6
# 6     6  4819     1
# 7     7  5120     1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Group,Date,Month,Sales,lag7,lag6,lag5,lag4,lag3,lag2,lag1,lag0(reference),lead1,lead2,lead3,lead4,lead5,lead6,lead7
Group1,42005,1,2503,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1
Group1,42036,2,3734,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
Group1,42064,3,6631,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0
Group1,42095,4,8606,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
Group1,42125,5,1889,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0
Group1,42156,6,4819,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0
Group1,42186,7,5120,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

Comment: This worked for me.. I had some NA values in the data as well, which i replace with a number except 0 and 1, and it worked for me. Thanks! Can you help me with the direction for part2 query. Also, the code that you have provided, can it be incorporated for groups using dplyr or shall i loop it for groups using the standard loop functon ?

Comment: @Jay I'll work on part2 part. In the mean time, one can use `apply` as part of `dplyr` chain after `group_by`.  Something like `mutate(match_count = apply(df[,-c(1:4)],1,function(x)..........`. Give it a try otherwise I'll update it after an hour.

Comment: Sure.. will check that.. Thanks a tone MKR!
You are a saviour! kudos!

If you have any thoughts on part2, just let know.. i will try it from my end as well.. i am looking for a direction, how to approach this problem.. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi MKR, I tried it in group function using mutate in Doyle function. It is giving me an error that “count” must be length 36 or one, not 72.

Comment: @Jay Sorry I have realized my mistake. I had meant to say that `mutate(match_count = ....` to go **before**  `group_by`. Since, your apply function is working on row-wise data hence it doesn't matter if `group_by` was not called before. Once mutate has been done you can use `group_by`.

Comment: No issues MKR.. since the logic that you mentioned basically works at the row level, hence group function is basically not required, as your logic does not vlookup any lag or lead rows.. hence its basically safe. pls correct me if i am wrong in my understanding.. Its the same thing that you mentioned in your previous comment.. Thanks again!