# identify consectuive rows that satisfy atleast one condition within a range of data

Tags: r

I would like to compare rows one by one and tag them as Case1,2,3 and so on, if they are similar for atleast one variable during that range of data series.The range is basically when the datapoint reaches it's first "1" value, during the to-and-fro movement from lag0(reference) for each row.

[data - highlighted yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUDna.png)

```
Group,Date,Month,Sales,lag7,lag6,lag5,lag4,lag3,lag2,lag1,lag0(reference),lead1,lead2,lead3,lead4,lead5,lead6,lead7
    Group1,42005,1,2503,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1
    Group1,42036,2,3734,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
    Group1,42064,3,6631,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0
    Group1,42095,4,8606,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0
    Group1,42125,5,1889,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0
    Group1,42156,6,4819,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0
    Group1,42186,7,5120,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0
```

For example,
When you compare row1 and row2, the highlighted yellow 0's are similar across atleast one variable during the range of to-and-fro first "1", hence this is case1. Now row2 and row3, are also similar across atleast one variable,during the range of to-and-fro first "1", and it is also adjacent to the previous case, hence this will also be case1( back to back case).

Row4 has nothing common with respect to previous and next row, hence this will not be captured.

Row5 and 6 are similar at atleast one variable, hence this will be Case2,

Row7 has nothing common with previous and next row, during the range of to-and-fro first'1,hence this will not be captured.

Expected output:

```
Month,Sales,Case
1,2503,1
2,3734,1
3,6631,1
5,1889,2
6,4819,2
```

My friend posted this earlier, by since we are struggling with time, hence bringing a fresh context to this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: I have to say that I struggle to understand your problem. Are you looking for consecutive `0`s across entries in column vectors? You state that *"Row4 has nothing common with respect to previous and next row"* but row 4 has a `0` in column `lag4`, where also all previous rows have a `0` in that same column. So I don't understand your statement.

Comment: Yes... row4 had 0 in column lag4, however that will not be part of the range of data, since range is basically when to-and fro data points from lag0(reference) till first 1 is achieved, at each row level. so for row4, lag1 and lead1 are 1, hence there is no zero between them, hence row4 has no range of data. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: I am looking to capture the consecutive rows, and tag them as case1,2 and so on, where for these consecutive rows their must be atleast one variable overlap- row by row within the range of data for at each row level, to ensure that these rows are connected to each other through a chain of series.

Comment: *"I hope that clarifies"* I'm sorry but no, not at all. I didn't understand a single thing you said in your first comment. Perhaps somebody else is quicker at picking up what you're trying to do. What do the case numbers refer to? Why `case1` and `case2`? Are these somehow related to the number of overlapping `0`s or `1`s? I also don't understand what you mean by "to-and-fro data points"?

Comment: If any number of consecutive rows overlap with each other, following the criteria i mentioned in my previous comment, then they will be tagged as case1. similarly, for the same group when i go down to further rows, i capture the same logic, the next level of consecutive rows will be tagged as case 2 and so on.. please check the expected results that i have mentioned in my post..

Comment: by to-and-fro i mean, if you keep lag0(reference) as the reference point, and move to the left, you will find few 0's till you reach first1, similarly when you move to the right, you will find few 0's till you reach first 1. combining both these cases with reference to lag0, you will get a range of series at each row level.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to agree with  @MauritsEvers, I've been trying to understand, but even with the explanations, I'm still struggling , can you add the link to your friend's question, maybe it can clarify the problem a bit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746911/complex-data-calculation-for-consecutive-zeros-at-row-level-in-r-lag-v-s-lead/50747252?noredirect=1#comment88507816_50747252